# VHDL Code for a Mealy machine with two inputs and one output

Tags: vhdl

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity lab2exercise2 is

    port
    (
    clk : in    std_logic;
    data_in1    : in    std_logic;
    data_in2    : in    std_logic;
    reset   : in    std_logic;
    data_out    : out   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    );

    end lab2exercise2;

    architecture rtl of lab2exercise2 is

    -- Build an enumerated type for the state machine
    type state_type is (a, b, c, d);

    -- Register to hold the current state
    signal state : state_type;
    signal clk_1hz : std_logic:= '0';
    begin
    process(clk)
    variable counter : integer := 0;
    variable edge_toggle : std_logic := '0';
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    counter := counter + 1;
    if (counter = 25000000) then
    edge_toggle := not edge_toggle;
    counter := 0;
    end if;
    end if;
    clk_1hz <= edge_toggle;
    end process;


    process (clk_1hz, reset)
    begin
    if reset = '1' then
    state<= a;
    elsif (rising_edge(clk_1hz)) then
    -- Determine the next state synchronously, based on
    -- the current state and the input
    case state is
    when a=>
    if((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    state<=a;
    if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    state<=a;
    if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    state<=a;
    else 
    state<=c;
    end if;
    when b=>
    if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '0')) then
    state<=a;
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    state<=d;
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1'))then
    state<=d;
    else
    state<=c;
    end if;
    when c=>
    if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0')) then
    state<=a;
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    state<=a;
    else if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    state<=d;
    else
    state<=b;
    end if;
    when d=>
    if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '1'))then 
    state<=d;
    else if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0')) then 
    state<=d;   
    else if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    state<=d;
    else
    state<=b;
    end if;
    end case;

    end if;
    end process;


    -- Determine the output based only on the current state
    -- and the input (do not wait for a clock edge).

    process (state, data_in1, data_in2)
    begin
    case state is
    when a=>
    if((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    data_out<= "000";
    if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    data_out<= "000";
    if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    data_out<= "000";
    else 
    data_out<= "010";
    end if;
    when b=>
    if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '0')) then
    data_out<= "000";
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0'))then
    data_out<= "011";
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1'))then
    data_out<= "011";
    else
    data_out<= "010";
    end if;
    when c=>
    if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0')) then
    data_out<= "100";
    else if ((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    data_out<= "100";
    else if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    data_out<= "111";
    else
    data_out<= "101";
    end if;
    when d=>
    if ((data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '1'))then 
    data_out<= "111";
    else if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '0')) then 
    data_out<= "111";   
    else if((data_in1 = '1') & (data_in2 = '1')) then
    data_out<= "111";
    else
    data_out<= "111";
    end if;
    end case;
    end process;

    end rtl;
```

This is my code. I tried running it but I always get error 10500 at lines 
"when b=>, when c=> and when d=>" and "end processes".
How do I run the code correctly?
This a Mealy machine btw and based from this.
A sequential circuit with two Dflip-flops Aand B, two inputs, xand y; and one output z specified by the following next-state and output equations.

```
A(t +1)=xy’ +xB
B(t +1)=xA+Xb’
z=A
```

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of the VHDL `if` statement is:

```
if condition1 then
  ...
elsif condition2 then
  ...
elsif condition3 then
  ...
else
  ...
end if;
```

If you use `else if` instead of `elsif`, you have several nested `if` statement and you need as many `end if`:

```
if condition1 then
  ...
else if condition2 then
       ...
     end if;
end if;
```

Comment: In addition to the question being unclear (Error 10500 is a syntax error, during analysis (compile) not simulation (running)), there is no concatenation operator for scalar type boolean -  e.g. `if (data_in1 = '0') & (data_in2 = '1') then`, those `&`'s should be `and` and none of the parentheses are needed, relational operators (=) are higher precedence than logical operators (and) - `if  data_in1 = '0' and data_in2 = '1' then`.  Port data_out has the wrong length declared (or all the assignment  expression values are wrong, or both).